# Including a file from included file. Referencing issue

Tags: php

Here's a sample file structure:

page.php 
db.php 
folder1/subpage.php 
folder2/fn.php

page.php

```
require_once('folder2/fn.php');
```

folder1/subpage.php

```
require_once('../folder2/fn.php');
```

folder2/fn.php - requires database connection

```
require_once('../db.php');
/* then gets info from database */
```

Basically, fn.php contains database functions to get/set information. It requires db.php, which is database connection file. This code works in subpage.php, but not in page.php (getting "failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ..." error).

Is there a way (using relative referencing), so that it works in all files no matter of directory level?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which file you include in page.php that is important.. you should put code of page.php for better understandability..

Comment: Rukmi: imagine that this is the whole code... there are no other files included in page.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the absolute path to the include. There are a couple ways to do this, this command will return the absolute path

```
<?php echo getcwd(); ?> 

But this is what I personally use: 
<? include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/analytics.php"; ?>
```

no matter where the file is php will have the absolute path.

Comment: another method would be to use dirname(__ FILE __), to get the absolute path of the current script that does the include

Comment: what about adding files outside of public directory? You cannot do www.example.com/../db.php, do you?

Comment: No paths have to be either absolute /hompages/public_html/include/db.php or relative include/db.php you can use a url if you were including a file from another server outside of your own this is done using cURL. If you want to include a file outside of your site root you would use the following homepages/dir_name/db.php you can either hard code the document root or your can do it dynamically using this piece of code <? include $SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/dir_name/db.php"; ?> Hope answers your question.

Comment: Also it is good practice to use include or require on all pages. Some people will have say index.php within they will include products.php and then within products.php they will include db.php If you are using both products.php and db.php include both of them within index.php it may work the other way but when it comes to debugging it makes your live a whole lot easier. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks Adam. I'll try it as soon as I get home. I personally don't like to include files within included files, but in this case php was giving me an error since I try to use mysql_query() inside of included file (even though it is inside of a function and not being called from the included file). Anyways, I'm including them in both index.php and fn.php.